# How to remove the second digit from right (0) in the following column in R? 200517302 200517801 200519101 200519702 200521002 200521205

Tags: r

How to remove the second digit from right (0) in a variable in R?

17302,
17801,
19101,
19702,
21002,
21205

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to match the character (`.`) followed the character captured as a group (`(.)`) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
as.numeric(sub(".(.)$", "\\1", v1))
#[1] 1732 1781 1911 1972 2102 2125
```

---

Or more compactly with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_remove(v1, ".(?=.$)"))
```

NOTE: If it is specific to 0, replace the `.` with `0` i.e.

```
as.numeric(str_remove(v1, "0(?=.$)"))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(17302, 17801, 19101, 19702, 21002, 21205)
```

Answer (score 1):

if  the second last digit is `0` then you can do:

```
x <- c(17302, 17801, 19101, 19702, 21002, 21205)

x %% 10 +x %/% 10 

[1] 1732 1781 1911 1972 2102 2125
```

Comment: Generalisable if it is not a `0` - `x %/% 100 * 10 + x %% 10`